# Network Printers

Tags: networking, printing

**Ubuntu 23.10** Using Cinnamon desktop.

Local Wifi network printers keep appearing and reactivating themselves in 'Printers-Local Host'. They show up as a 'Printer installed' dialog box on my screen.

In Printer Properties, Policies, I have repeatedly un-ticked 'Enabled' and 'Accepting Jobs'. A couple minutes to hours later, they are reactivated. There are three printers, probably located in the office for this RV park, on the local network, so they show up on my PC as a Notification regularly.

I was thinking of printing to them a notice that they are usable by random RV park transients, which could result in depleted resources, and perhaps they are stealing bandwidth from the Wifi signal, but first...before I do that or contact the office...

Is there a way to shut off these volunteer printers on my PC? Why doesn't my repeatedly resetting them by un-ticking 'Enabled' & 'Accepting Jobs' in Policies do anything? What are those settings for if the printer is allowed to reinstate itself (and not from rebooting...they just repeatedly reinstate all on their own)? I think this is the interesting question. Seems like a bug to me. But it is a network policy thing so maybe there's a setting I don't know about? Does anyone know how to shut these off?

Searching this forum shows that it's not a CUPS issue but the solution shown for Ubuntu 14.04 is rather dated and beyond my skills as it requires editing an obscure file & seems it would affect something else other then just the display of the unwanted printers.

Here's what that old post says, "I can confirm this problem. If you are on a network with self-announcing printers, on 14.04, (some of?) those printers show automatically up in the print dialog (at least of Xubuntu and Kubuntu). Stopping cups-browsed prevents cups from adding those printers, but still, they show up in the print dialog. So yes, this is not a cups problem. The problem is resolved by stopping avahi-deamon, which is not optimal. We need a solution which keeps avahi-deamon alive, but stops the print dialog from displaying those printers. –
azimut
Dec 9, 2014 at 11:01"

Comment: no it is not dated. It is correct. disable avahi-daemon. that services add printers,

Comment: Okay, I disabled avahi-daemon...what is that supposed to do? All three remote network printers still show up in my printers local host display. And I just got that notification again. And they have auto-reinstated, "Enabled" and "Accepting jobs". So nothing has changed that I can tell. I used:   systemctl disable avahi-daemon.socket and  systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service